# Background doesn't load on different pages with identical code

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I got two different registration & login interfaces, one for employees and the other one for external people.

I just copied the code from the employee pages and changed the routes, so everything is identical.

But for some reason on the external login & registration pages my background doesn't load with 404 error code, I have no idea why?

Has someone any idea why that is?

Here is the page where it is working:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')



    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-3/6 bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-70 p-8 rounded-lg font-serif text-2xl font-bold">

            @if (session('status'))
                <div class="text justify-center bg-red-500 p-4 rounded-lg mb-6 text-white text-center">

                {{ session('status') }}

                </div>
            @endif
            <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
                @csrf

                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
                           class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg @error('vorname') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                    @error('email')
                    <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>



                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Passwort</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Passwort"
                           class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg @error('vorname') border-red-500 @enderror" value="">

                    @error('password')
                    <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" class="mr-3">
                        <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-3 rounded font-medium w-full">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



@endsection
```

here is the page where it is not working:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-3/6 bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-70 p-8 rounded-lg font-serif text-2xl font-bold">

            @if (session('status'))
                <div class="text justify-center bg-red-500 p-4 rounded-lg mb-6 text-white text-center">

                    {{ session('status') }}

                </div>
            @endif
            <form action="{{ route('portal_login') }}" method="post">
                @csrf

                <div class="mb-4">
                    <h1 class="flex justify-center mb-10"> Bewerbungsportal Login </h1>
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
                           class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg @error('vorname') border-red-500 @enderror" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                    @error('email')
                    <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>



                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Passwort</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Passwort"
                           class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg @error('vorname') border-red-500 @enderror" value="">

                    @error('password')
                    <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" class="mr-3">
                        <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-3 rounded font-medium w-full">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



@endsection
```

Here is the default layout from app.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Finanzraketen</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <style>
        .hintergrund{
            background: url('background.jpeg');
            background-size: cover;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="hintergrund">
<!-- Navbar goes here -->
<nav class="bg-white shadow-lg bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 mb-10">
    <div class="max-w-full mx-auto px-4">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <div class="flex space-x-7">
                <div>
                    <!-- Website Logo -->
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center py-4 px-2">
                        <img src="rakete-2.png" alt="Logo" class="h-8 w-8 mr-2">
                        <span class="font-semibold text-black text-lg">Finanzraketen</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Primary Navbar items -->
                <div class="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-3 ">
                    <ul class="flex items-center pl-10 grid grid-cols-6 gap-10">
                    <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('home') }}" class="p-3">Home</a>

                    <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('overview') }}" class="p-3">Stellenanzeigen</a>

                        @auth()

                                <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" class="col-start-3 py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Dashboard</a>


                                <a href="" class="col-start-4 py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition border-gray-500
                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">{{ auth()->user()->email }}</a>


                                <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post" >
                                    @csrf
                                    <button type="submit" class="col-start-5 py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Logout</button>
                                </form>
                        @endauth


                        @guest
                             <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('login') }}" class="p-3">Mitarbeiter Login</a>


                               <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('register') }}" class="p-3">Registrieren</a>

                            <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('portal_login') }}" class="p-3">Portal Login</a>

                            <a class="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black rounded shadow transition
                    duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" href="{{ route('portal_register') }}" class="p-3">Portal Registrieren</a>
                            @endguest

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Mobile menu button -->
            <div class="md:hidden flex items-center">
                <button class="outline-none mobile-menu-button">
                    <svg class=" w-6 h-6 text-black hover:text-green-400"
                         x-show="!showMenu"
                         fill="none"
                         stroke-linecap="round"
                         stroke-linejoin="round"
                         stroke-width="2"
                         viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                        <path d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- mobile menu -->
    <div class="hidden mobile-menu">
        <ul class="">

            <li> <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('overview') }}">Stellenanzeigen</a> </li>
            @auth()
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="" class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300">{{ auth()->user()->email }}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post" class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit">Logout</button>
                    </form>
                </li>

            @endauth

                @guest
                    <li>
                    <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('login') }}" class="p-3">Mitarbeiter Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('register') }}" class="p-3">Registrieren</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a class="block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300" href="{{ route('portal_register') }}" class="p-3">Bewerbungsportal Login</a>
                    </li>
                @endguest
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector("button.mobile-menu-button");
        const menu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu");

        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
        });
    </script>
</nav>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

They are the same code wise, oney the route differs. They are even in the same directory

Comment: No, because we cannot see any code and that would be the only way we could do anything other than play 20 questions with you

Comment: If you ___changed the paths___ then everything is ___not identical___ And there is your most likely problem

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i dient change any path. both login blades are in the same directory, they use the same background image from the same directory aswell

Comment: You ___Specifically said___ _I just copied the code from the employee pages and changed the paths_

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh that is a typo, meant the routes. Always get them mixed up, sorry!

Comment: @RiggsFolly i solved it! :D :)) so happy right now!

Comment: @Frevelman Do not update your question with the answer. That is what the **answer** section is for.

Comment: @BrianThompson I wanted to, but I got the message that I cannot answer questions :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new pages where it didn't work had a "double" uri, like so:

```
Route::get('/portal/login', [PortalLoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('portal_login');
```

The pages where it worked had a single uri, like so:

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
```

I just had to add an additional / to style tag:

From

```
<style>
    .hintergrund{
        background-image: url('background.jpeg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

to:

```
<style>
    .hintergrund{
        background-image: url('/background.jpeg');
        background-size: cover;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot for proper answering, don't know why I couldn't! 

Hope at least one developer stumbles upon this when he/she has the same problem :D that would be great

Comment: You can if you like and I will delete this after you have removed the "Accepted" from it to add to your answer

Comment: when I try to post it states "we are no longer accepting answers from this account" :/

Comment: Maybe if you remove the Accepted answer tick it will let you

Comment: Or maybe its because of the downvote

Comment: no it was the same before you even posted the answer. I think I got some kind of ban, but I don't know why. I try to ask the question in the best way possible but my knowledge in correct terms is limited so it is hard to find the right words. maybe because of too many downvotes :( 

But at least there is a working answer now thanks to you! that's great :)

Comment: Ok, I did it as a wiki so I dont get any credit for it :)

Comment: would be totally fine if you get credit for it! You took the time to copy it, so future people have a proper answer, so everything is fine! Thank you and all the best! :)